# res.send(imgPath) does not send image when content-type is set to image

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

Response does not send the S3 image, instead I get the local route path:

```
route.get('/file');
res.setHeader('content-type', result.file_type);
res.send(imgPath);
```

I get the route path ('file') as a response, with black screen. What I want is to get the image

Answer (score 0):

Instead of send file path in response, please pass image data in binary format. Please use below code:

```
app.get('/file', function (req, res) {
    var img = fs.readFileSync('./logo.png');
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'image/gif' });
    res.end(img, 'binary');
});
```